# iOS Twitter reply dialog

Tags: ios, twitter

I want to add the ability to reply to tweets and would like to use the built-in dialog.  Is there any way to do this, or maybe a library that exists for this scenario?

I've tried simply adding `@username` as the initial text in the dialog, but it doesn't post it as a reply to a particular tweet:

```
SLComposeViewController* cvc = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];
cvc.completionHandler = ^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result) { };
[cvc setInitialText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"@%@", [self.tweet objectForKey:@"twitter_screen_name"]]];
[controller presentViewController:cvc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Is there a solution, or do I need to just manually create a dialog and style it?